# C# HTTPS Server on Ubuntu

Tags: c#, .net, ubuntu, https, mono

I'm trying to get an HTTPS connection working on Ubuntu from my C# HTTP server. I've enabled HTTPS in my HTTPListener as you would on Windows, however I am unable to establish a connection.

From the docs:

> If you create an HttpListener using https, you must select a Server Certificate for that listener. Otherwise, an HttpWebRequest query of this HttpListener will fail with an unexpected close of the connection.

I am seeing exactly this happen. The docs suggest:

> You can configure Server Certificates and other listener options by using Network Shell (netsh.exe). See Network Shell (Netsh) for more details. The executable began shipping with Windows Server 2008 and Windows Vista.

Since I am on Ubuntu and my server is running Ubuntu Server, I do not have access to this tool. How do I achieve the same effect in Ubuntu?

Comment: If you don't want to preconfigure a certificate via command line on Linux, you can generate a certificate on the fly,

https://github.com/jexuswebserver/RemoteServices/blob/master/RemoteServices/Program.cs

Comment: "preconfigure a certificate via command line on Linux" sounds like exactly what I'm trying to do here. Could you post an answer with how to do that?

Comment: If you prefer to run preconfiguration with CLI, then read http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/httpcfg.1.html You can write your own answer once the issue is resolved.

Comment: That actually hasn't fixed my issue. I need to use httpcfg as far as I'm aware and even then that isn't reading my certificate properly (and it is valid)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is dependent on the backend web server being used. On Ubuntu, you'd probably be using Kestrel. For Kestrel, an SSL certificate can be defined using:

```
"Kestrel": {
"Certificates": {
  "Default": {
    "Path": "<path>/fullchain.pem",
    "KeyPath": "<path>/privkey.pem"
  }
},
"Endpoints": {
  "Http": {
    "Url": "http://*:80"
  },
  "Https": {
    "Url": "https://*:443"
  }
}
```

in appsettings.json

For more information about how to set up SSL for Kestrel refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-6.0